# How do I implement search functionality for all my sql tables in MVC?

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm doing my own search engine for my site.I managed to get some results.but I can only get data from a sql table.

Right now the HTML form looks like this:

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("SearchResult","Home")" method="get" class="search-form">
 <input id="searchNm" type="search" placeholder="Search..." class="search-field" name="SearchText" value="">
     <button type="submit" class="search-submit">
             <span class="search-icon">Search</span>
    </button>
```

Controller:

```
LawyerDB context = new LawyerDB();
public ActionResult SearchResult(string SearchText)
{
    return View(context.Articles.Where(x=>x.ArticleContent.Contains(SearchText) ||x.Headline.Contains(SearchText) || SearchText==null).ToList());
}
```

Search Result:

```
@model IEnumerable<Law.Data.Model.Category>
@foreach(var item in Model){
    <article class="col-sm-12">
        <a href="@Url.Action("BlogDetails","Home",new { id=item.ArticleId})">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="@item.ArticlePhoto">
       </a>
            <div class="blockContent">
                <div class="blockTop">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("BlogDetails","Home",new { id=item.ArticleId})" class="layout-tittle" style="width:80%;" >@item.Headline</a>
                </div>
                <p class=" text-muted"><em><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time fa-fw"></i>@String.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy}", item.CreateDate) <span class="col-sm-offset-1"><i class="fa fa-comments-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>@item.Comments.Count()</span></em></p>
                <hr>
                @if (item.ArticleContent.Length > 150)
                {
                    <p>
                        <em>
                            @Html.Raw(item.ArticleContent.Substring(0, 150))
                        </em>
                    </p>
                }
                else
                {
                    <p>
                        <em>
                            @Html.Raw(item.ArticleContent)...
                        </em>
                    </p>

                }
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <a class="read-more" href="@Url.Action("BlogDetails","Home",new { id=item.ArticleId})">Read More<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                <hr>
            </div>
```

}

I could only do this for the article table at the moment.Is there a good way to do this for all the sql tables?

My sql tables:

```
 public virtual DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Authority> Authorities { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set;}
public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Label> Labels { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<SiteContent> SiteContents { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you considered using an actual search engine, such as Lucene? Beyond that, have you tried building the search as a SQL statement instead of using LINQ?

Comment: No I haven't tried.But with these codes I can get the values in the current article table as you like.Is not it possible to do this for all the tables?

Comment: I do not know if I can do exactly what I want with lucene

Comment: Waste of effort, use https://cse.google.com

Comment: I don't want to open the google tab when I search

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server I would suggest looking at the full text indexing feature.  It will do a lot more than your simple `.Contains` clause this will only show exact matches.  You'll need to do some more work to create a stored procedure.  I don't recommend trying to build a SQL statement from raw user input unless you're expecting Little Bobby Tables to drop in.